# Fswatch observing folder for new files error from the example doc

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to "listen in" on changes in a particular folder, then once a file comes in, I want to copy the file to another folder. I figured fswatch would be a great choice for this.

And as I'm reading through the official documentation of [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) and I see this snippet of code:

```
fswatch -0 path | while read -d "" event \
  do \
    // do something with ${event}
  done
```

I convert it to my folder and to print info about the event like so:

```
fswatch -0 '/home/ubuntu' | while read -d "" event \
  do \
    echo "WOOOW ${event}"
  done
```

And I got this error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token` done'`, anyone has suggestion how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do` must be preceded by a line break or a `;`.

I suggest to remove `\` after `event`.